# Excel VBA to read Code 128 barcode

Tags: vba, excel, barcode-scanner, excel-2016

I am trying to create a VBA code to read input from a barcode scanner. Specifically I'm interested in reading code 128 barcodes. I read on a different post that the barcode scanner is basically a "keyboard" that types the input when scanning to the application. I don't whether this can be replicated in Excel using VBA. Any ideas will be appreciated.
I am looking for something like this:

```
Sub BarcodeScannerReader()
   Dim sMyCode As String
   sMyCode=input("Scan Code:")
   Range("A1"). Value=sMyCode
End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look at this link [Create Barcodes With (Or Without) Excel VBA](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/create-barcodes-with-excel-vba)

Comment: Thank you @YasserKhail. However, this shows how to create the barcodes. What I would like read a barcode from a printed paper to a cell in Microsoft excel

Comment: The space between `Range("A1").` and `Value` would be illegal, for one. `Input` is a reserved keyword, used for reading text or binary data from files. So your question is basically, *what tools and/or libraries can I use with VBA to read barcodes?*, correct?

Comment: @Mat...let's say you have 123456678 barcode on a paper. I want to read this barcode and enter the read value (12345...) in a cell, say, A1.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Yes, what libs?

Comment: If you select a cell and read a barcode, then as long as your reader is configured to append a newline/enter after the barcode it will work just fine.  You don't need any code to do this, and there is no "translation" required: the reader will send the barcode value just as if you'd typed it in manually and hit Enter.  Should also work for inputbox.

Comment: A barcode scanner is nothing but a fancypants keyboard... treat it as you would a keyboard.

Comment: Ooh, OK! Looks like the solution is easier! Let me try

Comment: I used a scanner to read barcodes from products into excel for years.  It's really just point and scan.  If I remember it will just go to the next row of whatever column you are in.

Answer (score 0):

You need the barcode fonts installed, and your barcode reader set up to write to the cell you're interested in. The scanner really does work like a keyboard - it will read the code and 'type' the results wherever you direct it to. This isn't something you do in VBA (unless I'm misunderstanding your question).